# Using emberjs, data from git master in a Rails app

Tags: ember.js

It would be nice to use `ember.js`, `data` from `git HEAD`, since the project is moving so fast ;). `ember-rails` is mighty useful, and I definitely want to use that. It would be nice to add this to ember-rails, for people who want to use the latest ember assets.

```
rake g ember_rails:install
```

This actually copies the assets to the vendor/javascript folder.

Subsequent upgrades should be

```
rake g ember_rails:upgrade
```

This is of course one way of doing it. And there might be someway to do this already ?

Suggestions ? If needed, I could create a ticket for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, answering my own question:

`rails g ember:install --head`

does that. However, it does not vendor `ember-data`, `bootstrap` generated stuff depends on that. There is a [pull request](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails/pull/68) for that for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can link to them directly:

- `https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/downloads`
- `https://github.com/emberjs/data/downloads`

Comment: Github download links don't work on IE, as it doesn't intentionally set the correct content-types, as its not a cdn.